# unit testing a class that uses linq to sql

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I want to write unit test for a class that contains linq to sql codes . I mean inside each method I have created a new DbContext and done database jobs .

I searched the web . first I came to use repository and Unit of Work patterns but I figured out that DbContext itself is a unit of work and its dbset works as repositories . another point is that I think there is no need to test Linq part because it works as it should ( tested by .net team ) . I want to test the logic I have added to the code . so I decided to create an interface with necessary methods with two implementations , one uses linqToSql while another is just a mock . something like this :

```
    public interface IDbManager
    {
        bool Insert(MyEntity newEntity);
    }

    public class RealDbManager:IDbManager
    {
        public bool Insert(MyEntity newEntity)
        {
            using (DbDataContext db = new DbDataContext())
            {
                db.MyEntities.InsertOnSubmit(newEntity);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public class MockDbManager:IDbManager
    {
        public bool Insert(MyEntity newEntity)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

is the whole idea correct ? if so is this a correct implementation ?

is it possible to define DbDataContext as a class variable instead of creating new instance inside each method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right general idea for a start. Your Mock `Insert` method should save the entity to some in-memory store so that subsequent queries will return the inserted information, as would be expected. But the very basic idea of having an interface, with a 'real' and a 'mock' implementation is there.

Remember that when using your Mock in tests, you are testing your *other* code that uses the mock - not the mock itself.

As for defining the DataContext as a member variable; you could use an IDisposable pattern for it, like so:

```
public class RealDbManager:IDbManager, IDisposable
{
    DbDataContext db = new DbDataContext();
    public bool Insert(MyEntity newEntity)
    {
        {
            db.MyEntities.InsertOnSubmit(newEntity);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You would just have to be sure to dispose of your DbManager, then.

Comment: good point about mock . and to or not to define DataContext as a class variable , is there any benefits or it is just another way of doing things ?( I mean from viewpoint of standards and best practices .)

Comment: Depending on what form of DI/IoC you are using, that might fit right in or be extraneous. I would do what makes sense within your external patterns. But as far as the DataContext itself goes, it is perfectly fine to keep it alive for a *short* period of time if you have multiple transactions to perform within a single web request (as opposed to working with a raw Connection object, where you want to `close` it as quickly/often as possible).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The only thing I would avoid is to create an actual mocked class (in this case it should be called Fake), but using a mocking engine.

In your question you mention two kind of tests. First is testing the behavior of your class, the second is testing the integration of it. They seem the same but it's not.

In the first you need to mock your class to test its 'connection' against your other classes this way (using Moq):

```
  [Test]
  public void Test()
  {
       var entity = new Entity();
       var mocked = new Mock<IDbManager>();
       //you are telling the moq engine everytimes it finds an invocation of your repository
       //to return true as you did in you mocked class
       mocked.Setup( x => x.Insert( entity ) ).Returns( true );

       var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest( mocked.Object );
       //in this method you invoke your repository
       var ret = classUnderTest.DoSomething( entity );

       //assertions
       Assert.Equal( something, ret);

      //eventually you can verify that your repository has been hit once
      mocked.Verify( x => x.Insert( It.IsAny<Entity>), Times.Once);
  }
```

in the later as you correctly state, you have nothing to test on linq (Microsoft did it for us), but in case you need to verify the correctness of your linq you can do it only against a real db (or using a repository pattern against a fake repository). This is an integration test and it's has nothing to share with mocking.

To decouple your class from DbContext you could use repository pattern. Have a look at this article. http://dotnetspeak.com/index.php/2011/03/repository-pattern-with-entity-framework/